# Integer $x$ for which $x^4+x^3+x^2+x+1$ is perfect square.

Tags: number-theory, diophantine-equations

Integer values of $x$ for which $\bf{x^4+x^3+x^2+x+1}$ is a Perfect Square.

$\underline{\bf{My\; Try}}$:: Let $\bf{x^4+x^3+x^2+x+1 = k^2}$, where $k\in \mathbb{Z}$

$4x^4+4x^3+4x^2+4x+1 = 4k^2 = (2k)^2$

Now How can I proceed after that

Help Required,

Thanks

Comment: Did you mean to multiply both sides by $4$, or to perhaps use $(2k+1)^2=4k^2+4k+1$?  Note the trivial $x=-1$ solution.

Comment: http://arcsin101.wordpress.com/2009/02/25/x4x3x2x1-is-a-perfect-square/

Comment: @juantheron : $\:$ Should your first sentence start with "What are the" or "Are there"? $\hspace{1.49 in}$

Comment: When you multiplied by $4$ you forgot to multiply the $1$ by $4$.  When you include that, it doesn't look like progress.

Comment: See also: [Determining all the positive integers $n$ such that $n^4+n^3+n^2+n+1$ is a perfect square.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1270599) (and other posts [linked there](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/1270599).)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Hint:** For all but finitely many integer values of $k$, we have

$$ (2k^2 + k)^2 < 4k^4 + 4k^3 + 4k^2 + 4k + 4 < (2k^2 + k + 2 ) ^ 2 $$

Comment: Replace the second $<$ with $\le$ and there are no exceptions at all.  That's because $(2x^2+x+2)^2=4x^4+4x^3+9x^2+4x+4=(4x^4+4x^3+4x^2+4x+4)+5x^2$.

Answer (score 0):

We can just change this into a quadratic equation (or cubic equation, but that becomes very highly complicated).

$$\because x^4 + x^3 + x^2 + x + 1 = k^2$$

then this means that $x^2 + x + (1 - k^2 - x^3 - x^4) = 0$. This means that:

$$x = \frac{-1 \pm \sqrt {1 - 4(1 - k^2 - x^3 - x^4)}}{2}$$

And this means that:

$2x + 1 = \pm \sqrt {1 - 4(1 - k^2 + x^3 + x^4)}$ meaning that this root is odd if $x$ is an integer. But if that is so, then, the expression:

$$-1 \pm \sqrt{1 - 4(1 - k^2 - x^3 - x^4)}$$

is even $(2x)$. But is $x$ itself an even integer? We can test to see if $x$ is odd or even, but I will only be testing if it is even. So let's call this even number $2r$ and assume that:

$$(2r)^4 + (2r)^3 + (2r)^2 + 2r + 1 = k^2$$

$$16r^4 + 8r^3 + 4r^2 + 2r + 1 = k^2$$

Since all other values on the left hand side of the equation are even (except $1$), then this means that $k^2$ is odd because the sum of all the even numbers is another even number $2n$. And we know that $2n + 1$ is odd. And since $k^2$ is odd, then $k$ is odd. Where:

$$2n = r(16r^3 + 8r^2 + 4r + 2)$$

$$\implies 2n = r(r(16r^2 + 8r + 4) + 2)$$

$$\implies 2n = r(r(r(16r + 8) + 4) + 2)$$

$$\therefore \frac{2n}{r^3} = 16r + 8 + 4 + 2 = 16r + 14$$

Now we can form a real quadratic equation. If $2n/r^3 = 16r + 14$ then:

$$4r^2 + 14^{1/3}r - 2n = 0$$

$$r = \frac{-14^{1/3} \pm \sqrt{14^{2/3} - 32n}}{8}$$

$$r = - \frac{14^{1/3}}{2} \pm \sqrt {2n + \frac{14^{2/3}}{4}}$$

The equation just above this sentence is given by "completing the square". By simplifying this, we will be able to simplify the quadratic expression much easier. If so, we get that:

$$r = \frac{-14^{1/3} \pm \sqrt {8n + 14^{2/3}}}{2}$$

$\therefore$ $x$ cannot be an even integer since:

$$x = 2r = -14^{1/3} \pm \sqrt {8n + 14^{1/3}} = \frac{-1 \pm \sqrt {1 - 4(1 - k^2 - x^3 - x^4)}}{2}$$

$$\implies 2x = 4r = 2(-14^{1/3} \pm \sqrt {8n + 14^{1/3}}) = -1 \pm \sqrt {1 - 4(1 - (x^2 + x + 1))}$$

$$\therefore 2x = 4r = -112^{1/3} \pm \sqrt {32n + 896^{1/3}} = -1 \pm \sqrt {4(x^2 + x + 1) - 3}$$

To conclude, the equation $x^4 + x^3 + x^2 + x + 1 = k^2$ has no solutions in integers if $x$ is even and $k$ is odd, so we know that there is no value for $n$ to satisfy the equation. And just from the looks of it, I don't think there would be solutions if $x$ was odd and $k$ is even, but that is just out of pure assumption. For equations like yours, you can use quadratic formulas and "complete the squares" to solve for $x$ and use the example provided. Hope I helped! :)

Comment: I just love how I do not want to solve this through a cubic equation because it would be very complicated, and now looking back at my answer to this question a month later, I see that it is very complicated.

Comment: Don't know whether you are aware that $x=3$ and $(x^5-1)/(x-1)=11^2$ is a solution?